# Build Google Test like shared library

Tags: cmake, googletest

I have the project with many subprojects, and one of them is google test project.
I must build google test library as shared library every time when I build the main project, but single way to build the google test as shared is setting global option "`BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON`". Unfortunately, other projects are depended of this option. So, how to build google test as shared library in this case?

I tried to replace

```
cxx_library(gtest "${cxx_strict}" src/gtest-all.cc)
cxx_library(gtest_main "${cxx_strict}" src/gtest_main.cc)
```

with

```
add_library(gtest SHARED src/gtest-all.cc)
add_library(gtest_main "SHARED src/gtest_main.cc)
```

but it is no effect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing with GTest and GMock: shared vs. static libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237341/testing-with-gtest-and-gmock-shared-vs-static-libraries)

Comment: What's the quotation mark gefore SHARED?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possibilities: If you are not at liberty to change the gtest sources, set the `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` option before the `add_subdirectory` call for gtest, and reset it back immediately after:

```
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS_OLD ${BUILD_SHARED_LIBS})
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCED)
add_subdirectory(gtest)
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ${BUILD_SHARED_LIBS_OLD} CACHE BOOL "" FORCED)
```

Alternatively, if you do want to change the gtest sources, replace the `cxx_library()` with calls to `cxx_shared_library()`:

```
cxx_shared_library(gtest "${cxx_strict}" src/gtest-all.cc)
```

This is required because the `cxx_library_*` macros set [some additional stuff](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/cmake/internal_utils.cmake#L148) for the build that a plain `add_library` would miss.

Note that you might still want to keep `gtest_main` as a static library, as it defines the entry point (aka `main()`) for your program and moving that to a shared library might not have the effect that you intended.

Comment: First work fine for me. But second produce linker errors.

Comment: @voltento What linker error? You might have to set `gtest_force_shared_crt` on Windows if you get conflicts for runtime functions, but otherwise, it should work just as well. In any case, the first solution is probably preferable, as it is less intrusive.

Answer (score 3):

Set variable `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` to the desired value before stepping into googletest project and restore the variable after that.

Because googletest defines *BUILD_SHARED_LIBS* as option (that is, cached variable), it is better to assign *initial cache value* to that variable before inclusion of googletest.

```
# Need to assign value for cache variable explicitely.
option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build shared libraries" OFF)
...
# Store old value
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS_OLD ${BUILD_SHARED_LIBS})
# Assign desired value for subproject
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)
# Step into subproject
add_subdirectory(gtest)
# Restore old value
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ${BUILD_SHARED_LIBS_OLD})
```

Note, that for temporary value's changing you needn't to modify cache: it is sufficient to set **normal variable**. This is possible because of CMake policy of processing normal and cache variables with the same name.