# How to build and use GoogleTest shared library (.so) using g++ on Linux?

Tags: gcc, g++, shared-libraries, googletest

> **NOTE** it's not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513905/how-to-setup-googletest-as-a-shared-library-on-linux) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42643002/build-google-test-like-shared-library).

How to build Googletest **from source** using g++ into a shared library (.so)?

I tried the steps described in [Google Test's document](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/README.md#as-a-shared-library-dll) on how to build a shared library, but linking the produced `libgtest.so` with my test programs didn't work - the linker throws *tons* of errors like:

> "gtest-all.cc:(.text+0x19b50): multiple definition of `testing::internal::HasNewFatalFailureHelper::~HasNewFatalFailureHelper()'libgtest.so:gtest-all.cc:(.text+0x19b50): first defined here
>   ./libgtest.so: In function `testing::internal::HasNewFatalFailureHelper::~HasNewFatalFailureHelper()':"
>   gtest-all.cc:(.text+0x19bc4): multiple definition of `testing::internal::HasNewFatalFailureHelper::ReportTestPartResult(testing::TestPartResult const&)'
>   libgtest.so:gtest-all.cc:(.text+0x19bc4): first defined here
>   ./libgtest.so: In function `testing::internal::TypedTestCasePState::VerifyRegisteredTestNames(char const*, int, char const*)':

When building `libgtest.so`, I used command:

`g++ -fPIC -DGTEST_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY=1 -pthread -c $(GTEST)/src/gtest-all.cc -shared` (this macro is required in the aforementioned Google Test's document) and then `mv gtest-all.o libgtest.so`

When linking with `libgtest.so`, I used load flag `-DGTEST_LINKED_AS_SHARED_LIBRARY=1`, as recommended in the aforementioned Google Test's document. I also used `-L` flag to tell g++ where the library is.

**NOTE:** if I choose to build a `libgtest.a` archive from source and link my test program with this archive, everything is fine (instructions on how to build it is also in that [Google Test document](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/README.md#build)). The reason why I'd like to switch from `libgtest.a` to `libgtest.so` is I want the executables to load GoogleTest at runtime so linking might be faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found.

**step 1**. build object file `gtest-all.o`

> g++ -fPIC -isystem ../path/to/googletest/include -I../utils/third-party/googletest/ -pthread -c ../path/to/googletest/src/gtest-all.cc

It's recommended by [GoogleTest's doc](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/README.md#as-a-shared-library-dll) to add a macro flag `-DGTEST_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY=1` to the command above.

**step 2**. compile shared library

> g++ -fPIC -shared gtest-all.o -o libgtest.so

**Then**, to link against the shared library

Be sure to use `-Wl,-rpath=./path/to/libgtest.so` flag. There is no white space between `-Wl,` and `-rpath` (`-Wl,option` means passing `option` to linker. [more on -Wl,option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options)). It's recommended to add flag `-DGTEST_LINKED_AS_SHARED_LIBRARY=1`.